# How to control memory consumption while multithreading

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, web-scraping, queue

I am trying to **scrape** some websites using the `python`'s `threading` and thread-safe `queue` module. I'm observing an increase in memory usage as I test on more URLs. Below is my code for your reference:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from queue import Queue
from threading import Thread
import itertools
from time import time
import newspaper
import requests
import pickle

data = defaultdict(list)
    
def get_links():
    return (url for url in pickle.load(open('urls.pkl','rb')))
#     for url in urls[:500]:
#         yield url

def download_url(url):
    try:
        resp = requests.get(url) 
        article = newspaper.Article(resp.url)
        article.download(input_html=resp.content)
        article.parse()
        data['url'].append(url)
        data['result'].append(article.text)
    except:
        pass

class DownloadWorker(Thread):

    def __init__(self, queue):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.queue = queue

    def run(self):
        while True:
            # Get the work from the queue and expand the tuple
            link = self.queue.get()
            try:
                download_url(link)
                print(link,"done")
            finally:
                self.queue.task_done()
                print(self.queue.qsize())

def main():
    ts = time()
    links = get_links()
    
    # Create a queue to communicate with the worker threads
    queue = Queue()

    # Create worker threads
    for x in range(4):
        worker = DownloadWorker(queue)
        # Setting daemon to True will let the main thread exit even though the workers are blocking
        worker.daemon = True
        worker.start()
        
    # Put the tasks into the queue as a tuple
    for link in itertools.islice(links,1000):
        queue.put(link)

    # Causes the main thread to wait for the queue to finish processing all the tasks
    queue.join()
    pickle.dump(data, open('scrapped_results.pkl','wb'))
    print('Took %s mins' %((time() - ts)/60))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If tested on 100 URLs the memory consumption stays constant at 0.1% but it increases as the more number of URLs are tested (0.2%,0.4%,0.5%). Max URLs I have tested are 1000. The mix of questions I have is below:

- Why memory consumption increase?
- Is memory increasing because the queue not getting emptied before it gets filled? My understanding of `queue` is that it empties itself as the data in the queue gets processed.
- Is there a way to keep the memory usage constant by the threads?
- Is it because of the data in the `defaultdict` is getting bigger?
- Can timeout help here? Where can I declare a timeout?
- Is it the `newspaper` and `requests`?

Comment: *Is it because of the data in the `defaultdict` is getting bigger?* That would be my first area of investigation. If you keep adding data, memory consumption is going to increase.

Comment: Hi @JimMischel - yea, I investigated that and change the scrip to write it to a file but the memory still increases after a certain number of URLs.

Comment: What is "a certain number of URLs"? Does memory consumption increase without bound, or is it perhaps that the garbage collector isn't feeling memory pressure, so it's not cleaning up?

Comment: I checked, actually the `article.parse()` is causing the memory increase. It increases after around processing 200 URLs without bounds. When I just use `requests.get`, it works fine